# Laravel: How to ignore database field's special characters when doing a 'LIKE' query?

Tags: laravel

I want to ask for your help as I'm having challenges creating a Laravel query.

Here's my current code:

```
$products = Product::where(function($query) use ($searchTerm) {
   $query->where('product_name', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%");
   $query->orWhere('product_category', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%");
   $query->orWhere('product_description', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%");
   })
   ->where('lang', '=', 'en')
   ->orderBy('product_name', 'ASC')
   ->get();
```

If I have a product named *Michael's Handsoap* and the user searches using the keyword *"Michaels"*, it returns nothing with the above query. Is there a way to remove special characters from database fields as you do the query? Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Figured that it's best just to add a `product_name_search` column that contains the product name stripped of special characters (using, for example, `preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $productName)`)

This way, `$query->where('product_name_search', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%")` can now be used. It adds another parameter, but at least you've covered them all now.

Comment: try  "%$searchTerm%" to  "%{$searchTerm}%"

Comment: Or try "%$searchTerm%" to "%".$searchTerm."%"

Comment: Thanks for the response John Lobo and SirMissAlot. Unfortunately, none of them work.

Comment: Try this - if the last character in $searchTerm is letter s, strip that and then your query should work.

Comment: This is harder to solve with a database query. This is a limitation of not using a search engine like [Apache Solr](https://solr.apache.org/). I would solve your case with a database field of synonyms where you add alternate spelling and add an `orWhere` for that.